# Set XML as Value of XElement

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

My method receives a XML string as the input and I need to put this XML string into XML envelope using `XElement`:

```
input:                     <hello>Hello!</hello>
expected result: <envelope><hello>Hello!</hello></envelope>
```

The problem is that this code:

```
string xmlHello = "<hello>Hello!</hello>";
XElement xelem = new XElement("envelope", xmlHello);
```

escapes all `<>` and so the result is:

```
<envelope>&lt;hello&gt;Hello!&lt;/hello&gt;</envelope>
```

Is there any way to disable this behaviour of the `XElement` constructor to be able to accept XML as the value? The input string can be really huge, so I would like to avoid parsing it.

Comment: Why do you need to disable escaping of this value? What about potential case when it will contain `</envelope>` substring? It will break your xml if will not be escaped.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev You are right, that would be a problem. However, I check if the input string follows one of possible XSD schemas, so there is no risk of `</envelope>` substring.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Unfortunately, this check is done by different module of the system, so my method does not receive parsed XML, just a plain string.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Thanks, I missed that! This `XRaw` from the question is probably what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, this can't be done directly as the API has no way of knowing your text is actually well formed XML unless you pass it something it knows is an XML element.

So what you need to do is parse your XML first:

```
string xmlHello = "<hello>Hello!</hello>";

var hello = XElement.Parse(xmlHello);

var envelope = new XElement("envelope", hello);
```

Resulting in:

```
<envelope>
  <hello>Hello!</hello>
</envelope>
```